# put tab before every output line on AIX/ksh

Tags: sed, aix, ksh

```
0:root@SERVER:/root # echo "something" | sed -e 's/^/\t/g'
tsomething
0:root@SERVER:/root #
```

AIX/ksh .. why doesn't it works? I just want to put a "tab" before every line!

Comment: What happens if instead of typing "\t" you press Ctrl-V then press Tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\t` on the right hand side of a `sed` expression is not portable. Here are some possible solutions:

### POSIX shell

Bear in mind that since many shells store their strings internally as cstrings, if the input contains the null character (`\0`), it may cause the line to end prematurely.

```
echo "something" | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '\t%s\n' "$line"; done
```

### awk

```
echo "something" | awk '{ print "\t" $0 }'
```

### Perl

```
echo "something" | perl -pe 'print "\t"'
```

Comment: Is pointless to specify `perl`'s `-n` switch here. `-p` implies the `-n`'s effect.

Answer (score 1):

If your shell is bash, ksh93 or zsh, you can use shell escaping to put a literal tab in the sed command. The quoting syntax `$'…'` treats every character inside the quotes literally except for backslashes and single quotes. You can use the usual backslash escapes inside these quotes.

```
sed -e $'s/^/\t/g'
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aezVyqif

Comment: @LanceBaynes Then I presume you have ksh88.