# Replace @@@ and NotApplicable string and redirect output to other file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, aix

I'm using IBM AIX which doesn't have much support like `sed -i` and sed with `\t` is not working in my case.

I would like to replace replace `NotApplicable` string with a `single space ' '` then replace `@@@` multi-char-delimiter with a `tab delimiter`, in a specified order using single command be it awk, or sed.

I tried using sed as following but it didn't work. Couldn't add search and replace for NotApplicable with a ' ' single space in below command.

> sed 's/@@@/\t/g' file.csv > file.xls

Sample data.

```
cola@@@colb@@@colbc
test@@@test@@@test
test@@@NotApplicable@@@test
123@@@145@@@567
333@@@444@@@NotApplicable

cola    colb    colbc
test    test    test
test            test
123     145     567
333     444
```

Comment: If you're just doing this from the command line (not writing a script which should pass code review ;-)) you can simply enter the tab manually with Ctrl-v Tab. (your command will look like `sed s/@@@/       /g ...`)

Answer (score 1):

Translating [Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26597/117549) to this situation, it'd be:

```
sed $'s/@@@/\t/g; s/NotApplicable/ /g' file.csv > file.xls
```

This uses ANSI-C quoting to allow interpretation of `\t` as a TAB; everything else inside the quotes is the existing `sed` command.

Comment: I like to replace NotApplicable to single space ' ' as well using same sed.

Comment: see edited Answer

Comment: Didn't work in my case.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? The changes don't happen? You get an error?

Comment: Data is redirected as is with `@@@` and `NotApplicable` string to be precise.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I don't think that the ksh88 (?) on AIX has support for `$'...'`.

Comment: ksh93 is on recent, supported AIX versions, so as a work-around: `ksh93 -c "sed $'s/@@@/\t/g; s/NotApplicable/ /g' file.csv > file.xls"`

Comment: [AIX 5.3](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/systems/power/docs/aix/53/baseadmndita_pdf.pdf) and [AIX 6.1](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/systems/power/docs/aix/61/baseadmndita_pdf.pdf) (as well as 7.1+) Operating system and device management guides list ksh93 as available.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more obvious ways to do it, but one way to generate any character on any unix system is with tr(1):

```
tab=`echo t | tr t '\011'`
sed "s/NotApplicable/ /g; s/@@@/$tab/g" file.csv > file.xls
```

Notice the *double* quotes around the `sed` command.